# How to replicate this screenshot in WebForms?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox, coding-style

I need to replicate the following in ASP.NET WebForms using a GridView.

[image]

But I am not sure where to start.  Basically I need 3 columns.  The checkbox (which sometimes needs to be disabled), and 2 standard text columns.

I've gone through the tutorial and I can see how to basically dump text data into a GridView, but not clear on how to implement checkboxes, particularly ones that needs to be disabled once in a while.

And I have to replicate the style of the screenshot (e.g. border on the bottom).  Having trouble with that as well.

How do I swing something like that?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a nice article on **[Adding a GridView Column of Checkboxes](http://www.asp.net/Learn/data-access/tutorial-52-vb.aspx)**